# DictWriter deletes all data?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I'm trying to write a script that uses dictionaries to match paired rows within a CSV and then combines those pairs.

The script right now works until the last section, when I'm trying to create the output file. Instead of rewriting the file with the paired rows, it just deletes all information in the file.

```
fn = "test.csv"
import csv
with open(fn, "r", encoding = "UTF-8") as inputfile:
    rows = list(csv.DictReader(inputfile))
row_dict = {r["number"]: r for r in rows}
r_v_pairs = {}
for ref, row in row_dict.items(): 
    s1 = (ref, row["Obverse"])
    s2 = (row["Obverse"], ref)
    if s1 in r_v_pairs:
        r_v_pairs[s1].append(row)
    elif s2 in r_v_pairs:
        r_v_pairs[s2].append(row)
    else: 
        r_v_pairs[s1] = [row]
r_v_pairs = list(r_v_pairs.values())
def combine_rows(rows):
    if len(rows) < 2:
        pass
###there's a problem here if there is only one. it's probably a corrupted file.
    elif len(rows) > 2:
        pass
###there's a problem here if there are more than 2. it's probably a duplicate.
    else:
        new_row = {}
        r1, r2 = rows
        return new_row
new_rows = [combine_rows(rs) for rs in r_v_pairs]
new_rows = [r for r in new_rows if r]
with open("test.csv","w", encoding='utf-8') as output_file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file)
    writer.writerows(new_rows)
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample file so that we can reproduce your error?

Comment: sure, here's a test file https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1a01JeXCMNJhOjF7WDKOqOQoboUcJGpUEnrkE7x1kHA4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Your test file gives **KeyError: 'number'**, useless.

Comment: the test file is the just a subset of the master csv, so i'm not sure how to fix that (different) test error

Comment: The script expects a "number" column.  The test data doesn't have that.  Also don't post links, add a short sample to the question.  See [mcve] guidelines.  Make sure the code with the input data reproduces your issue.